# Solving a second order BVP for $y(x)$ with a singularity in $y$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, boundary-value-problem

I am looking to find a numerical solution to the following second order non-linear BVP for $x \in (-100,0)$ with k,$\gamma$>0.

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = k(y-1) - \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx}(\gamma + \frac{dy}{dx}) $$
with boundary conditions, 
 $$  \frac{dy}{dx}(-100) = 0, \quad y(0)=0. $$
I've attempted to solve this problem with MATLAB's boundary value solver BVP4C; however there is a problem with the $1/y$ term (I believe). When I remove this term I get a sensible solution. Any suggestions about how I can either overcome this problem and use BVP4C, or use a different method to get the solution? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the equation to
$$
\frac12(y^2)''=ky(y−1)−γy'\\
((y^2)'+2γy)'=2ky(y-1)
$$
Thus formulate the first order system for $u=y^2$, $v=u'+2γ\sqrt{u}$ as
$$
u'=v-2γ\sqrt{u}\\
v'=2k(u-\sqrt{u})
$$
or with the other sign of the root to explore a negative solution for $y$.

The roots might still render the Jacobian in the BVP solver singular
which should be less singular.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try this, and let you know if it works. Can I ask how you thought of this transform? I’m a new PGR student so it’s always helpful for me to understand how one thinks of these strategies.

Comment: Just looking what terms go together. Reducing the depth of differentiation by combining derivatives into one derivative of an intermediate term can increase the smoothness of the problem description so that numerical methods work (better).

Comment: Okay. So do you decide on the transformation first? Or the other way round? I would be grateful if you could add a few more lines to your answer including how you came up with the transforms.

Comment: It was really just recognizing the combination of terms $yy''+y'^2=\frac12(y^2)''$. You can do similar for slight variations of this equation, seeing that $(y^a)''=ay^{a-2}(yy''+(a-1)y'^2$, but more radical changes will "destroy" this trick.

Comment: This answered my question correctly and gave me the answer that I was expecting. :)

Comment: Okay, so I generated another ODE and transformed it via the rule you stated above and got $  (3(y^{2}) '  - 2(y^{3}) '+6 \gamma y)' = ky(y-1) $. I attempted both the substitutions $ u = y^3$ and $u = 3y^{2} - 2y^{3}$ but to no success. Could you suggest a substitution to use? Many thanks.

Comment: The second version should work, but is only valid as long as the solution stays on one of the monotonous branches of that cubic function.

Comment: I don't think this will work however, due to the term $6\gamma y'$ and $ky(y-1)$. Since we aren't able to rearrange explicitly for $y$... Have you any suggestions about how to deal with this?